# Помогите разобраться как сделать пагинацию

Tags: php, wordpress

Сделал шаблон для WP на страницу выводятся записи и прикрепленные документы, но совсем забыл о том что когда их много то страница превратится в полотно, как мне сделать пагинацию, у самого пока не получается страница сразу падает

```
        <section>
        <?php
        $documents = get_field('documents');
        $mime_types = array('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' => 'doc.png',
            'application/pdf' => 'pdf.png',
            'application/msword' => 'doc.png',
            'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' => 'xls.png',
            'application/zip' => 'zip.png',
            'application/vnd.ms-excel' => 'xls.png');
        foreach ($documents as $documents_group) {
            ?>

            <div class="document-grpup">
                <h4><?php echo $documents_group['header'] ?></h4>
                <p class="description"><?php echo $documents_group['description']; ?></p>
                <?php
                $files = $documents_group['files'];
                if (count($files) > 0) {
                    foreach ($files as $file) {
                        ?>                          
                        <a href="<?php echo( $file['file']['url'] ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/documentIcons/<?php echo $mime_types[$file['file']['mime_type']]; ?>" height="41" width="32" alt="pdf" class="icon"> <span><?php
                        if ($file['file_name'] != '') {
                            echo $file['file_name'];
                        } else {
                            echo( $file['file']['title'] );
                        }
                        ?></span></a>
    <?php
    }
} else {
    echo 'Документы отсутствуют';
}
?>          
            </div>

<?php } ?>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Для создания пагинации в рубриках стоит использовать [the_posts_pagination()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/the_posts_pagination), а для пагинации постов [wp_link_pages()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_link_pages). Вот [руководство](https://wp-kama.ru/id_8428/paginatsiya-dlya-otdelnoj-zapisi-ili-stranitsy-v-wordpress.html) по созданию пагинации постов (рус.) включая добавление кнопки разбивки поста в визуальный редактор.

Принцип работы и примеры пагинации в **wordpress** есть в [кодексе](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination).

Либо использовать плагины, например: [WP-PageNavi](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/), [WP-Paginate](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-paginate/)